# Would water-based rain float on top of large sea of liquid mercury?

Tags: environment, sea

I was thinking about a setting where two large landmasses are separated by a sea of mercury. Obviously, iron boats would float. In fact, the ships would have to be extremely heavy.

What would happen to normal water-based rain if it fell on this sea? As water is less dense, would it float?

Comment: This is a very open ended question where any potential effect is an equally valid answer. Can you instead try to [edit] this question down to ask a single specific question. You have a couple of sub-questions can you instead ask about one and only one of those. We have a strict one question per post policy so asking both in one post would be prohibited.

Comment: The question parameter is not about the 'liquid mercury' bit. it is about the environmental conditions needed to keep the mercury liquid. The goldilocks zone - not too hot, not too cold. Will rain actually fall under those conditions? If so, then the mercury would be at the very bottom of any open body of water, all of the rain would float on top, and if there is enough water and the ocean deep enough, the mercury would be under several atmospheres of pressure. Doubtful the mercury would have any effect on the surface except on the toxicity of the water.

Comment: "According to Jefferson Labs, mercury’s melting and freezing point is -38.8 degrees Celsius; this is far lower than that of water. Its boiling point is 356.7 degrees Celsius, 629.9 Kelvin or 674.1 degrees Fahrenheit, far higher than water. At room temperature, mercury is a liquid. " https://www.reference.com/science/freezing-point-mercury-eb9afe6846b67710

Comment: I was the last close-voter and I agreed that this is inherently a duplicate of the earlier question, but let me point out that the Q is also in violation of a couple of [help] rules. (a) No open-ended, hypothetical questions, (b) violation of the Book Rule (too broad), (c) brainstorming and leading to a discussion (SE is not a discussion forum). (d) More than one question. We'll help you build your world by answering specific questions, but this is asking us to give you an education in the chemistry, biochemistry, physics, mechanics, and toxicology of mercury. That's way too much.

Comment: Please remember that we have a strict requirement of one question per post. Asking would the water float on mercury, is a different question than asking would the water be toxic. If you [edit] down to one of those I think your question would be suitable for reopening.

Comment: @AngryMuppet Questions that self answer, are technically valid, even though they may show a lack of research. We assess questions for reopening based on the current revision. It's no-longer a duplicate, and we regularly answer questions that may be obvious, or even self answering if you have the correct knowledge.

Comment: Fair enough. Seems one of those charming quirks we have here. It does lend itself to speculation about what would happen in the coldest places, if the water froze but the mercury kept responding to tidal pull. @sphennings

Comment: @AngryMuppet That sounds like a very cool follow up question. Maybe you should ask it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## It Floats

Any drop of water that would hit the water, even if it had enough energy to pierce the surface, would experience a buoyant force pushing it upwards.

We need to remember that [Archimedes' principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes%27_principle) applies to all fluids. Even fluids within fluids! This is the same reason why heavier than air gasses can be especially dangerous when collecting in holes, ditches, and other low-lying areas. It's also why hot air balloons work: the extra heat in that air changes its density and therefore it rises. Same goes for water on mercury.

Comment: Oil on water might be a more familiar example. And not only will the water float on the mercury, but so will the mud, sand, and stones. It's a bit of a problem to explain how you'd ever get to see the actual mercury layer, and why it hasn't all sunk to the core of the planet.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff Well, your styrofoam cup will float on water. But yet you can still drink water from it.

Comment: @Topcode a styrofoam cup forms a water-tight barrier with enough structural strength to withstand the forces involved in containing water. Planetary crusts are full of cracks and other defects and an ocean of mercury would easily produce enough pressure to deform rock. Look at what salt domes do, deposits of solid salt bubbling up through rock because of the density difference...you'd see the mercury doing the opposite, sinking right through the rock, while also seeping through whatever crack it can find.

Answer (score -3):

Yep, the water would indeed float on top of the mercury, just like oil floats on top of water.

Comment: Welcome TS. This doesn't add anything substantive to Pipperclip's answer. You might have left a comment as you've sufficient rep to do so. See: [answer].